# Programming Hangman in Java, exception in main thread error (along with others)

Tags: java, exception, program-entry-point

So I have this program somewhat functional so far.  I've been using switch statements.  I'm not sure if that's proper logic for this, but I have it working.  When I input the word I want, it works, and starts drawing the hangman after the first input, but then runs into an error.

```
                public class Hangman {
                     public static void main (String[] args){
                       JFrame frame = new JFrame ("Hangman");
                       frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

                       HangmanPanel Panel = new HangmanPanel();

                       frame.getContentPane().add(Panel);
                       frame.pack();
                       frame.setVisible(true);

                    }


                  }
```

here's my other class

```
   import javax.swing.JPanel;

import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.*;

import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class HangmanPanel extends JPanel {
    int lives;
    String guessletter;
    String inputw;
    char[] hiddenWord;
    char[] aOfWord;
    String[] words = { "ADA", "COBOL", "LOGO", "BASIC", "PROLOG", "UBUNTU",
            "UHURU" };

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean isFound;
    int a;

    public HangmanPanel() {

        System.out.println("Enter the word to be searched: ");
        inputw = scan.nextLine();

        aOfWord = inputw.toCharArray();
        this.setLives(inputw.length());
        // this.output();

        hiddenWord = new char[aOfWord.length];

        for (int j = 0; j < hiddenWord.length; j++)
            hiddenWord[j] = '*';

        this.output();

        while (lives > 0)
            System.out.println("Please choose a letter: ");
        guessletter = scan.nextLine();
        this.checkForMatch(guessletter);
        if (isFound == true) {
            hiddenWord[a] = guessletter.charAt(0);
        } else {
            System.out.println("_____");
            System.out.println("|   |");
            System.out.println("|   ");
            System.out.println("|   ");
            System.out.println("|   ");
            this.reduceLives();

            while (lives > 0)
                System.out.println("Please choose a letter: ");
            guessletter = scan.nextLine();
            this.checkForMatch(guessletter);
            if (isFound == true) {
                hiddenWord[a] = guessletter.charAt(1);
            } else {
                System.out.println("_____");
                System.out.println("|   |");
                System.out.println("|   o");
                System.out.println("|    ");
                System.out.println("|    ");
                this.reduceLives();

            }

            while (lives > 0)
                System.out.println("Please choose a letter: ");
            guessletter = scan.nextLine();

            this.checkForMatch(guessletter);
            if (isFound == true) {
                hiddenWord[a] = guessletter.charAt(2);
            } else {
                System.out.println("_____");
                System.out.println("|   |");
                System.out.println("|   o");
                System.out.println("|   | ");
                System.out.println("|    ");
                this.reduceLives();
            }

            while (lives > 0)
                System.out.println("Please choose a letter: ");
            guessletter = scan.nextLine();

            this.checkForMatch(guessletter);
            if (isFound == true) {
                hiddenWord[a] = guessletter.charAt(3);
            } else {
                System.out.println("_____");
                System.out.println("|   |");
                System.out.println("|   o");
                System.out.println("|  /| ");
                System.out.println("|    ");
                this.reduceLives();
            }

            while (lives > 0)

                System.out.println("Please choose a letter: ");
            guessletter = scan.nextLine();

            this.checkForMatch(guessletter);
            if (isFound == true) {
                hiddenWord[a] = guessletter.charAt(4);
            } else {
                System.out.println("_____");
                System.out.println("|   |");
                System.out.println("|   o");
                System.out.println("|  /|\\ ");
                System.out.println("|    ");
                this.reduceLives();
            }

            while (lives > 0)

                System.out.println("Please choose a letter: ");
            guessletter = scan.nextLine();

            this.checkForMatch(guessletter);
            if (isFound == true) {
                hiddenWord[a] = guessletter.charAt(5);
            } else {
                System.out.println("_____");
                System.out.println("|   |");
                System.out.println("|   o");
                System.out.println("|  /|\\ ");
                System.out.println("|    \\");
                this.reduceLives();
            }

            while (lives > 0)

                System.out.println("Please choose a letter: ");
            guessletter = scan.nextLine();

            this.checkForMatch(guessletter);
            if (isFound == true) {
                hiddenWord[a] = guessletter.charAt(6);
            } else {
                System.out.println("_____");
                System.out.println("|   |");
                System.out.println("|   o");
                System.out.println("|  /|\\");
                System.out.println("|  / \\");
                this.reduceLives();
            }


        }
        this.output();

    }

    public void setLives(int a) {
        this.lives = a;
    }

    public void reduceLives() {
        lives = lives - 1;
        System.out.println("Lives remaining: " + this.getLives());

    }

    public int getLives() {
        return lives;
    }

    public void output() {
        System.out.println("Lives remaining: " + this.getLives());
        System.out.println("Word found so far ");

        for (int i = 0; i < hiddenWord.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(hiddenWord[i] + "\n");
        }

    }

    public void checkForMatch(String l) {

        for (int i = 0; i < aOfWord.length; i++) {

            if (l.charAt(0) == aOfWord[i]) {
                isFound = true;
                a = i;
                break;
            } else {
                isFound = false;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Post the Error here please?

Comment: You do not `break` or `return` after each `case`, so possibly your code is running proceduraly and giving you unexpected errors.

Comment: I don't think breaks would matter much in this case since all cases are mutually exclusive.

Comment: Sorry  This is the error "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 4
 at java.lang.String.charAt(Unknown Source)
 at HangmanPanel.<init>(HangmanPanel.java:115)
 at Hangman.main(Hangman.java:12)

Comment: @MxyL the OP should remove teh `switch` statement then if that's the case, since it's not needed. Good form to have `break` so you can understand program flow, especially since he has a `loop` iterating over the case until `lives` are <= 0.

Comment: @snakedoc.  Thanks.  To be honest, I'm a total noob, and if I remove the switch, I'm not sure how I'll get it to draw a hangman.  I was trying to manually have it draw the hangman after each error.  Should I just use a while loop?

Comment: You can use `if, else if, else if ...` That is logically equivalent to a switch case without having to worry about any breaks. I never remember to add breaks, so I never use a switch that requires breaks.

Comment: if you loop, then @MxyL is right, you can use `if, else if, else` structure to step through the game stages.

Comment: The exception that is being thrown is telling you that there is a String array someplace in HangmanPanel line 115 that you are trying to access outside teh array bounds, meaning you are trying to get element 5 for example, but the array only has 4 elements, etc. Usually, it's just a counter that's off by 1 somehow...

Comment: Ok.  So should I keep the while loop the same?  Just get rid of switch and add if else?

Comment: either that, or add `break` after you complete a `case` which will return control to the loop, it will test your condition of `lives > 0` and if true, it will flow back into the case, then flow to the correct case, do that stuff, then break, then back to loop, etc. over and over until `lives` is 0 or less.

Comment: @user3019802 with programming, there's always multiple ways to skin a cat ;-P  just have to find the way that works for you with the least errors lol.

Comment: @snakedoc.  haha.. thanks.  I run into a lot of errors now.  Sucks being a noob :P.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you've got this covered by now, but I was curious, so I made a shot at your classes, and commented my changes. Hopefully you, or someone else, can get some use of it :-]

```
// renamed from Hangman
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // removed need for JFrame as no GUI is actually used.
        Hangman hangman = new Hangman();
        // starting a thread with the hangman runnable
        new Thread(hangman).start();

        // main thread will end here, but the hangman thread will keep the program running. 
    }
}
```

Then the actual Hangman class:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;


// Renamed from HangmanPanel, changed from JPanel to Runnable since no GUI is shown.
public class Hangman implements Runnable {

    // always use 7 lives, as this is the number of "hangman images" in reduceLives()
    private int lives = 7;

    private char[] hiddenWord;
    private char[] aOfWord;

    // I'm guessing that at some point you will use these randomly? 
    private String[] words = { "ADA", "COBOL", "LOGO", "BASIC", "PROLOG", "UBUNTU", "UHURU" };


    @Override
    public void run() {
        // This is the new Try-With-Resources in Java 7.
        // If you don't have Java 7, just change the 
        // try ( Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in) ) {
        // to
        // try {
        //   Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        try ( Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in) ) {

            System.out.println("Enter the word to be searched: ");
            String inputw = scan.nextLine();

            aOfWord = inputw.toCharArray();
            hiddenWord = new char[aOfWord.length];

            // nice method for filling an array.
            Arrays.fill(hiddenWord, '_');

            // renamed from output
            showStatus();

            // fixed outer while-loop
            while (lives > 0 && Arrays.equals(aOfWord, hiddenWord) == false) {
                System.out.println("Please choose a letter: ");
                String guessletter = scan.nextLine();
                if(guessletter.isEmpty()) {
                    System.out.println("You must enter a letter. Try again!");
                } else {
                    checkForMatch(guessletter);
                }

                // refactored all inner loops into checkForMatch() and reduceLives()
            }

            System.out.println("Game over, you " + (lives > 0 ? "won" : "lost"));   
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private void checkForMatch(String letter) {
        boolean found = false;

        for (int i = 0; i < aOfWord.length; i++) {
            if (letter.charAt(0) == aOfWord[i]) {
                found = true;
                hiddenWord[i] = letter.charAt(0);
                // removed break when found to allow searching entire word
            }
            // removed else condition to avoid clearing 'found' when searching rest of word
        }

        if(!found) {
            // reduceLives() will also print new hangman 
            reduceLives();
        }

        // printing summary
        showStatus();
    }

    private void reduceLives() {
        lives = lives - 1;

        switch (lives) {
        case 6:
            System.out.println("_____");
            System.out.println("|   |");
            System.out.println("|   ");
            System.out.println("|   ");
            System.out.println("|   ");

            break;
        case 5:

            System.out.println("_____");
            System.out.println("|   |");
            System.out.println("|   o");
            System.out.println("|    ");
            System.out.println("|    ");

            break;
        case 4:
            System.out.println("_____");
            System.out.println("|   |");
            System.out.println("|   o");
            System.out.println("|   | ");
            System.out.println("|    ");

            break;
        case 3:
            System.out.println("_____");
            System.out.println("|   |");
            System.out.println("|   o");
            System.out.println("|  /| ");
            System.out.println("|    ");

            break;
        case 2:
            System.out.println("_____");
            System.out.println("|   |");
            System.out.println("|   o");
            System.out.println("|  /|\\ ");
            System.out.println("|    ");

            break;
        case 1:
            System.out.println("_____");
            System.out.println("|   |");
            System.out.println("|   o");
            System.out.println("|  /|\\ ");
            System.out.println("|    \\");

            break;
        case 0:
            System.out.println("_____");
            System.out.println("|   |");
            System.out.println("|   o");
            System.out.println("|  /|\\");
            System.out.println("|  / \\");

            break;
        }

    }

    private void showStatus() {
        System.out.println("Lives remaining: " + lives);
        System.out.println("Word found so far " + new String(hiddenWord));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  It is helpful.  I couldn't quite figure it out for my assignment, so I just handed it in to get some credit.  But it's nice to see how it works.  I copied and pasted this into my editor.  I'll definitely use this as a reference in the future.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your code performs a fall through as it is written now. It enters a case and since you don't have a **break** it goes to the next case. You need to enter a **break** after each else statement in your cases.

Example

```
case 1:
            System.out.println("Please choose a letter: ");
            guessletter = scan.nextLine();
            this.checkForMatch(guessletter);
            if (isFound == true) {
                hiddenWord[a] = guessletter.charAt(0);
            } else {
                System.out.println("_____");
                System.out.println("|   |");
                System.out.println("|   ");
                System.out.println("|   ");
                System.out.println("|   ");
                this.reduceLives();
            }
            break;                                   // Add this for each case
```

Comment: Thanks.  Just tried that.  I'm still getting an exception in main thread error.  I'm gonna try removing switch statements and do if else

Comment: Ok. Best of luck if you have any more questions feel free to ask. Also you said you are a beginner so here is a link to a good book that I would recommended your read. [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/gxcpyl686r8fg5r/Prentice.Hall.Introduction.to.Java.Programming.Comprehensive.8th.Edition.Jan.2010.pdf)

Comment: Thanks man.  Well, I changed all those switch statements to   while (lives > 0) then if else for each and every one.  Not when I run it, it prints out "Please choose a letter" in an infinite loop

Comment: So your problem with the code above is its only going to enter into the first while loop and then constantly print out the statement because lives is always going to be greater than zero. I recommend you read the book in the link and then try coding up to this. It will take a lot of work to fix this code.

Comment: I don't really have time to read the whole book.  It seems like my teacher gives assignments above our skill level to test us.  I downloaded the book, and I'll start reading it during xmas break.

Comment: Yes, I would try and help you more but I have to study for my finals. The code is fixable and maybe next weekend when my finals are over I can look through it and fix it and send it to you. As of now it would take a good couple hours to go through and check everything.

Comment: Thanks Chris.  Yeah, I'm doing my finals now too.  I hear ya

Comment: @user3019802 I would try posting a brand new question with your current code as well as your current stacktrace printout from your exceptions. list it as a new question because you have solved the previous question, this way nobody gets mad you are double posting. Fresh questions get a lot more attention.

Comment: Ok thanks Snake Doc.  Maybe I'll try to delete this one. I found out that I don't need to put it in a GUI.  I just need to get the computer to play the game using the brute force method. Totally confused by that..